# How to get project to use resources from another project?

Tags: android

I have a simple activity that I use in many apps. The layout is the same, but the only thing that is different is the drawables used in the activity.

So, say I have this simple activity (A) defined in its own project with its own layout file. Is there any way for me to import A into other projects B and C, but to use their own drawables? So while using the layout from A, B would fill it with all of its resources and so on. Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a library containing the shared resources, then importing that into each project?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I'm hoping to have the activity and layout be shared, and the resources be individual to each application that uses those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, create your library project: http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject

```
public class MySharedActivity extends Activity(

int drawable1;
int drawable2;

//Your stuff here
)
```

Then, in your Project B, C:

```
   public class BlaBla extends MySharedActivity(
   //Somewhere in your code:
   this.drawable1=R.drawable.localpicture
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there any way that I can just make MySharedActivity automatically get all of its resources from Project A, B, C? They would have the same name in each project.